# The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: html

I am using the following code to generate pdf from web page using itextsharp dll.

But i am getting the foloowing error .
The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

My code :

```
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();

        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
```

Comment: Do you use a proxy server to get into the internet and that thing needs some kind of authentication?

Comment: Does your sw.ToString() contain images (for instance) which are not hosted on the local server? The obsolete HTMLWorker does a lot work behind the scene.

Comment: Please remove itextsharp as tag. This isn't an itextsharp question. It's about getting HTML and all the resources that are referred to from that HTML on your machine.

Comment: My sw.ToString() does not contain any images .

Comment: I am working on office internet i tried with no proxy and all other settings still no result suggest me if there any additional settings need to be done .

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and I solved it by removing the url from the *!DOCTYPE html* tag in my html file.

i.e, I replaced:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

After making this change the HtmlParser.Parse command ran properly and produced the .pdf without giving me the (407) Proxy Authentication Error.